# dplyr unsupported type error when filtering

Tags: r, dplyr

I run this code and try to do a filter using the dplyr package and I get an error. Error: column 'USUBJID' has unsupported type. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
 library('SASxport')    
 library('dplyr')    

 dm<-read.xport('C:/Temp/SDD/dm.xpt')   

 filter(dm, SEX=="M")
```

Error: column 'USUBJID' has unsupported type

I got the same error with the following:

```
dplyr::filter(dm, SEX="M")     
dm %>% filter(dm, SEX=="M")
```

Here is some metadata for the file:

```
meta <-select(dm, USUBJID, SEX)
str(meta)
```

'data.frame':   816 obs. of  2 variables:

```
$ USUBJID:Classes 'labelled', 'character'  atomic [1:816]   .. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Unique Subject Identifier"

 $ SEX    : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": - attr(*, "label")= chr "Sex" - attr(*, "label")= chr " "- attr(*, "SAStype")= chr " "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an example data from `?read.xport`

```
library(SASxport)
w1 <- w$TEST[1:2]
w1 %>%
    filter(RACE=='blue')
#Error: column 'AGE' has unsupported type
str(w1)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ RACE: Factor w/ 3 levels "green","blue",..: 2 NA
# .- attr(*, "SASformat")= chr "RACE"
# $ AGE :Classes 'labelled', 'integer'  atomic [1:2] 30 31
#  .. ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Age at Beginning of Study"

w1[] <- lapply(w1, function(x) {
                   attr(x, 'SASformat') <- NULL
                   attr(x, 'label') <- NULL
                   x})

class(w1$AGE) <- NULL
w1 %>% 
   filter(RACE=='blue')
# RACE AGE
#1 blue  30
```

Based on the above example, I guess for the `meta` data

```
meta[] <- lapply(meta, function(x) {
               attr(x, 'SAStype') <- NULL
               attr(x, 'label') <- NULL
               x})

class(USUBJID) <- NULL
filter(meta, SEX=='M')
```

#### data

```
 testFile <- system.file('extdata', 'test2.xpt', package="SASxport")
 w <- read.xport(testFile)
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. Can you explain why it was necessary to remove the attributes and Class? I am new to R and thought since it was a valid data frame that it would work with dplyr

Comment: @user1476427  I think it is because `dplyr` supports only some `classes`.  May be in the future, it will extend to more class, attributes etc.  It could be due to speed concerns.